# Connect to a Read Only database

Tags: java, spring

While trying to connect to a database that's set to read only, the connection cannot be made.  I get the following error:

```
Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (Io exception: The Network Adapter could not 
establish the connection)
```

The application needs to run in read-write mode and then automatically handle the switch to read-only by only checking the isReadOnly property of the connection object.  The application runs correctly when connecting to a read-write database, but fails when I change to the connection string below (with security information removed).  I've verified that the connection string is correct, so the problem doesn't lie there.

```
ca.businesssolutions.nbs.jdbc.connect=jdbc:oracle:thin:unicorn_read_only/password@(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=hostname)(PORT=9999)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SID=SBSBTST)(SERVER=DEDICATED)))
```

I'm having trouble trying to figure out where to start looking.  I inherited the application and am not sure if it's a spring framework limitation or another setting I'm missing.

The spring configuration for the datasource is:

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="ca.businesssolutions.nbs.server.base.datasource.MyBasicDataSource"
      destroy-method="close">
    <!--url and driver class name are set through Configuratoin object.-->
    <property name="initialSize" value="10"/>
    <property name="maxActive" value="-1"/>
    <property name="validationQuery" value="SELECT 1 FROM DUAL"/>
    <property name="accessToUnderlyingConnectionAllowed" value="true"/>
</bean>
```

The Data Source constructor:

```
public MyBasicDataSource() {
    super();
    setUrl(Configuration.get(Configuration.CONNECT));
    setDriverClassName(Configuration.get(Configuration.DRIVER_NAME));
    //The initial number of connections that are created when the pool is started.
    int numConnections = 10;
    try {
        numConnections = Integer.parseInt(Configuration.get(Configuration.NUMBER_OF_CONNECTIONS));
    } catch (Exception exception) {
        // Do nothing.
    }
    setInitialSize(numConnections);
    //The maximum number of active connections that can be allocated from this pool at the same time, or non-positive for no limit.
    setMaxActive(-1);
    setValidationQuery("SELECT 1 FROM DUAL");
    setAccessToUnderlyingConnectionAllowed(true);
    DataAccessObject.setDataSource(this);
}
```

What else would help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's the difference between read/write and read-only connect string? Is there *any chance* for  a typo? Have you tried this connect string from another tool (but from the same host)? Try using a Java GUI Tool on the same computer that you have difficulties connecting from. Use Copy/Paste with your exact connection string.

If this doesn't work either, you might have an unresolvable hostname, firewall issues or something else. If it does work *from the same computer* leave a comment.

Comment: Thanks.  I found the typo.  It was an unresolvable hostname.